# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in on line 8

Tags: php, wordpress

```
      <?php if($images && is_array($images) && count($images > 0)):
      foreach($images as $image): 
        $image_full_src = false; $image_thumb_src = false;
        if($image_full_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'full')) $image_full_src = $image_full_src['0'];
        if($image_thumb_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'thumbnail')) $image_thumb_src = $image_thumb_src['0']; 
      ?>
```

how can i fix it eror?
it is with wordpress

Comment: You have a typo in this line: `count($images > 0)`, it should be `count($images) > 0`

Comment: wooow thanks a lot bro it was correct thanks...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 <?php if($images && is_array($images) && count($images) > 0):
  foreach($images as $image): 
    $image_full_src = false; $image_thumb_src = false;
    if($image_full_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'full')) $image_full_src = $image_full_src['0'];
    if($image_thumb_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'thumbnail')) $image_thumb_src = $image_thumb_src['0']; 
  ?>
```